# VueJS 1.0 : how to use a method of a component itself in an attribute?

Tags: vue.js

I have defined a VueJS component `my_button`, with a property '`caption`' and a method '`click_button`'.

I use this component in another VueJS component

```
<template ....
    <my_button 
      caption="test" 
      v-on:click="click_button"
    >
    </my_button>
</template>
```

The problem is that when I click the button it complains about the `click_button` function being in the wrong scope (apparently of the parent component instead of `my_button`).

How can I make it refer to the `click_button` of `my_button` ? I tried this.click_button and $this.click_button, but of course that didnt work.

Comment: Put it on the root element of the template in the `my_button` component definition

Answer (score 0):

I imagine that in your `my_button` component, you have a button. There, do something like:

```
<button onClick="click_button">{{caption}}</button>
```